# Export Active Directory data when Active Directory is not running

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

We have Windows Server 2008 Standard which had an instance of Active Directory (AD) running on it. Couple of days ago our Server crashed and we could not get Active Directory to fire up.

We are trying to install AD on a backup server(Windows 2008). However to actually create all entries (usernames, groups, passwords, permissions) from scratch is rather difficult :(. I was wondering if there are any utilities to fetch this information from the disk (As a newbie, I am wondering if AD stored this information in a flat file or DB that can be queried...Please correct me if I am wrong.)

We are using Windows Backup and we are in a position to fetch any files/folders pertaining to AD from past backups.

Any pointers would be appreciated. Please comment if you need any additional information. Thanks!

Comment: No additional DC then?

Comment: Err... If you're using Windows backup, surely you have the system state captured, which includes an online AD backup.  You just need your backup data, a working server, and NTDSUTIL.EXE.  Am I missing the point?

Comment: yea just one DC

Comment: Definitely just do a restore of this machine onto new hardware from your backups.

Comment: @SimonCatlin thanks for this ...I just found about NTDSUTIL.exe and it sounds promising...I am going over it now +1 for this suggestion

Comment: @mfinni We are using Windows Backup in Full Backup mode( which says it includes files/folders, applications and state). However, after our system crashed...and we tried to recover 'application' but it is greyed out so we can only recover files (albeit not all of them especially from System or C:).

Comment: @Vikram  Yes, AD is a queryable database, and at least in theory, you could extract the data from your backups... but man, does that sound like all kinds of not a good idea.  Do a full restore instead of trying to do this piece-meal.

Comment: @HopelessN00b thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely just do a restore of this machine onto new hardware from your backups. (copying from comments.)